# How can I tell if a docker container is on localhost or 192.168.99.100

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Is it possible in docker-compose or through some environment variable to figure out the hostname that docker is linking to containers?  The wordpress home and siteurl are set to localhost:8000 which work fine on docker for mac, but when used on docker toolbox for windows, the site is hosted on 192.168.99.100:8000, which then redirects back to localhost and fails.  Is it possible to determine whether the host is localhost or 192.168.99.100 in docker-compose?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the application is running inside a docker container, or are you trying to find out what the host IP is?

Comment: Docker on mac and linux will result in localhost, docker for windows (using hyper-v, ..) is also localhost. Only docker-toolbox or docker machine will have 192.168.99.100 because they are actually just sort of VM's on your machine (mostly used on windows instances without hyper-v)

Comment: I'm trying to find out what the host IP is.  It is only used in docker, but not every machine is hyper-v capable.  Wordpress has a home variable that's set in a config file, and attempts to access at other hosts automatically redirect there, so if for example I set the home to localhost and it is then spun up on toolbox, the request to 192.168.99.100 is redirected to localhost, which causes the problem.  I'd like to be able to somehow figure out the host so I can set the config appropriately on both environments

Answer (score 0):

I wound up putting together a simple bash script in the root folder that asked for input on what host the user wanted to use (localhost vs 192.168.99.100) and piped the answer to a .env file (https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules).  I then passed that environment variable to the relevant containers in docker-compose.yml.  Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it worked in a pinch.